# VBA Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with VBA for Excel.
I get the "Application defined or object defined" error each time I run this code.
Here it is:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, t As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim Maturite As Integer
Dim tsup As Double, tinf As Double
Dim datetaux As Date, datejouissance As Date
Dim taux As Double

For i = 2 To 770
Maturite = Sheets("Em").Cells(i, 19)
datejouissance = Sheets("Em").Cells(i, 14)
 For l = 2 To 255
    For k = 0 To 10
    For t = 1 To 10
        row = 13 * k + 2
        datetaux = Sheets("TSR").Cells(row, l)
    taux = Sheets("TSR").Cells(13 * k + 3, l)
    If taux <> 0 Then
     If datejouissance = datetaux Then
         If 91 <= Maturite And Maturite <= 182 Then
         tsup = Sheets("TSR").Cells(row + 2, j)
         tinf = Sheets("TSR").Cells(row + 1, j)
         Sheets("Em").Cells(i, 21).Value = ((tsup - tinf) * (Maturite - 91) / (182 - 91)) + tinf
         End If
End If
End If
Next
Next
Next
Next
End Sub
```

I get the error at :

```
     tsup = Sheets("TSR").Cells(row + 2, j)
```

I tried using :

```
     tsup = Sheets("TSR").Cells(row + 2, j).Value
```

The type of Sheets("TSR").Cells(row + 2, j).Value is Double.
But it's not working. I can't seem to understand what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show screenshots of `Em` and `TSR` sheets so we can understand how the cells are arranged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to check the value of j. As far as I can see from your code its value remains 0. Column 0 does not exist and will lead to the given error.

Comment: Didn't pay attention to that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You address the cell using the integer `j`, but you don't assign a value to `j`.
Thus, VBA fills it with the standart value for integers: `0`, directing your call to `Sheets("TSR").Cells(row + 2, 0)` and producing an error.